# Convert Matlab Fuzzy Logic toolbox fis file to c# / c++ / javascript

Tags: c#, javascript, matlab, fuzzy-logic

I have a Matlab program that is partially relies on Matlab's Fuzzy logic toolbox, which I want to convert to c# program (and later on to objective-c, but let's keep this for later).
Is ther any means to convert my fuzzy logic fis file into c# (or c++, or maybe even javascript)?

P.S. I know the `deploytool` can convert my program to exe, but I don't want to rely on `matlab runtime` component and dlls but to make it a complete c# (or c++) program.

Comment: @oleksii - the main program is .m file, but it uses the fuzzy logic toolbox and the .fis file. The question is about converting the Matlab's .fis file into other programming languanges.

Comment: check [this](http://www.mathworks.com/matlabcentral/newsreader/view_thread/288766) link, seems to be a similar aim

Comment: @oleksii - your link contains an answer with 4 out of 4 non-working links, but thanks for the try.

Comment: see someone has left incorrect chars in the end of the URLs, try clicking on the links and once the page loads (saying there is no such resource), remove the last few chars in the URL, like ");". This works for 3 out of 4 links and meaningful relevant data is displayed.

Answer (score 2):

Of course, you would know Mathlab Builder which converts your m files to .Net components but depends on Mathlab runtime. I have a lot of similar experiences, and I am afraid that you have to basically find c# library imitating the toolbox and convert your mathlab program into c# accordingly. Finding the library or converting process will not be as difficult as you would think. But validation test would be a big task if your routines are complex enough because you need to match mathlab results to those of your c# program with most possible combinations. My recommendation is to take agile approach and plan/write the validation tests before you work on the conversion.